# Valid characters for Firestore document ID

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I can't seem to find the following information in the Firestore docs:

1. What characters are valid to use in a document ID?
2. What characterset is used to generate a Firestore `AutoID`?

Comment: @doug-stevenson I would argue that this question is only half duplicated, since the second part of my question remains unanswered. Is marking this as a duplicate your way of saying I should create a new question only asking #2?

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, disregard my last comment. Even though it seems to be generating only alphanumeric IDs, it probably makes sense to assume any of the allowed characters listed on the other answer could be used for an Auto-ID in the future. Since a reliable answer to #2 would be unlikely, I agree this is a duplicate.

Comment: If you have two questions, it's a good idea to ask in two posts separately.  Technically speaking, asking multiple questions classifies this as "too broad" and could be closed on that point alone.

Answer (score 12):

You will find the responses in this documentation item: 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#collections_documents_and_fields

> Constraints on document IDs
>
> - Must be valid UTF-8 characters
> - Must be no longer than 1,500 bytes
> - Cannot contain a forward slash (/)
> - Cannot solely consist of a single period (.) or double periods (..)
> - Cannot match the regular expression `__.*__`